# How to receive GET request in an Angular page?

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I'm developing Angular app where user opens a URL (https://localhost:4200/bookingDone) fills the forms.

After that user clicks on PAY button and a POST request is fired to server to payment gate way with this

```
postBackURL: 'https://localhost:4200/oilChanger'
```

After creation of token on server. Server fires a GET call back to my angular app using url provided in postBackURL. How can I handle is call and route the UI to the oilChanger. I get this error in console:

> GET    https://localhost:4200/oilChanger?auth_token=1876038377738301950287234324&postBackURL=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2FoilChanger  0 ()
>
> core.js:1350 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}

Now problem is that my corresponding Angular Page that I configured for that Callback URL is not opening. I configured /oilChanger page in RouteProvider, but that seems not to be working.

However, if I open the url directly via browser, it gets opened.
my http call:

```
this.http.post('https://abcd.com/Index.jsf', body.toString(), options).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response)
    });
```

How this scenario can be handled? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I configured /oilChanger page in RouteProvider, but that seems not to be working." Then, why don't you show your RouteProvider or some more code? This is quite light to help you here!

Comment: Please show more html and js code.

Comment: Are you sure you need post request to `'https://abcd.com/Index.jsf'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to receive GET request in an AngularJS page?

You can't.

Angular is a client-side JavaScript framework.

HTTP requests are received by servers, not clients.

---

1. You need to run an HTTP server (you need one to deliver the Angular app to clients anyway).
2. You need to use a postBackURL that the service you are using can use to access that server. `localhost` means "This computer" and the service making the postback request will have a different idea about what "this computer" is to your web browser.
3. You need to handle the postback request on your HTTP server. How you do that will depend on what you want to do with the information in the request. If you need to get it back to Angular, then you'll probably want to *also* set up a WebSocket connection between your Angular app and your HTTP server.